# How to get this data sent to from index.js to script.js using express (Node JS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Beginner here...so bear with me :)

I'm getting this dataset in the console, but I can't wrap my head around getting it sent to the client side...

```
const { response } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`));

const translate = require('sdapi').default.translate;
translate('hablar').then(console.log);
```

This is the result I get:

```
[
  {
    word: 'hablar',
    lang: 'es',
    gender: undefined,
    context: 'to articulate words',
    meaning: 'to speak',
    part: 'intransitive verb',
    examples: [ [Object] ],
    regions: []
  }]
```

I've tried wraping it into a `app.get('/translation', async (req, res) => {})` but it doesn't work.

Appreciate your time/attention.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get('/translate/:word', async (req, res) => {
  const {
    params: { word },
  } = req; // same as const word = req.params.word
  const translatedWord = await translate(word); // same as .then

  return res.status(200).json({ translatedResponse: translatedWord });
});
```

To activate this you have to send http get request to whateverip:port/translate/<WORD_TO_TRANSLATE_INPUT>

You can send http requests with axios, curl, or fetch and your browser's terminal thouhg the last one isn't always optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to check your controller and sed data to it
so the first step that u must do to install `body-parser` with `npm i body-parser`

then use it like

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

now u can receive and store your data on request.

then learn about the request  (https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

then u can send a request to your server with postman or Axios or curl and something else .

I hope to solve your question.